# Как в одном запросе поменять значения двух аналогичных ячеек в соседних строках

Tags: mysql

Мне надо перенести данные с одной строки на другую, я делаю так:

```
update `articles` set `t`='10',`text`='new',`text2`=(SELECT `text2` from `articles` where `id`=2) WHERE `id`=1
```

Мне пишет:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table `articles` for update in FROM clause
```

Как правильно написать запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql такая штука, что тебе сначала как бы нужно получить данные, и только потом обновить.

Ибо нельзя обновить данные получая их тут же. Это фишки мускула.

## 1093 Недопустимо в одном запросе читать и менять значения одной и той же таблицы. Это приводит к коллизии.

Comment: можно ли это както обойти?

Comment: можно. причем первые ссылки гугла, реально с примерами. Там быстрее увидеть решение чем здесь сидеть и ждать!

Answer (score 0):

Вот например [решение](http://ramzes.ws/blog/cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause). Внутренний подзапрос переделать как select from select. Тогда для него будет использоваться временная таблица, никакой блокировки не будет и обновление успешно выполнится.